# ActionBar Drop-down Navigation custom layout style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

How can I style ActionBar Drop-down Navigation spinner in my custom layout?

Also, how can I change the size of a spinner?

I'm inflating custom layouts in getView() method of my custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_navigation_dropdown, null);
    }

    txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
    return convertView;
}
```

I was trying to change layout size in list_item_navigation_dropdown.xml but it only affects the text value of a spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I style ActionBar Drop-down Navigation spinner in my custom
>   layout?

The only part of the `Spinner` you can theme is the background by applying your own style using the `actionDropDownStyle` attribute. Here's an example:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/Your.Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_background</item>
</style>
```

> Also, how can I change the size of a spinner?

I think you're asking how to change the layout params of the `Spinner`, in which case you can't.

The `Spinner` in the `ActionBar` is created internally using the [`ScrollingTabContainerView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java#L204). By default the width is set to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` and the height is set to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`. But nothing in the `ActionBar` API allows you to modify the size of the `Spinner`.

An alternative is to use `ActionBar.setCustomView` and inflate a layout that contains your own `Spinner`.